# Why should Client Creadentials be associated with a user in Laravel Passport?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I want to use Client Credentials to authenticate client applications to access the API.

My problem is with creating client credentials. Using `php artisan passport:client` requires me to enter a user_id to associate the client to that user. I don't get it. Why the client application has to be associated to a user?! Or Is there another way?

passport:client command only supports creating Password Grant Clients and Personal Grant Client. I don't think that any of them is what I need.

What I really need is to create client credentials that will only be used by the client application to authorize itself to access some APIs. How to do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I assume you want to use machine-to-machine authentication (no user interactions)

I would recommend to read through the docs a couple of times to get the hang of it.

I do not believe there is an specific way to create an only client credentials client, What i do is to create an personal client then change the field for personal client in the database `personal_access_client` `1` => `0`

You could use the personal client option, as seen from the `--help` option

```
Usage:
  passport:client [options]

Options:
      --personal        Create a personal access token client
      --password        Create a password grant client
      --name[=NAME]     The name of the client
  -h, --help            Display this help message
...
```

`php artisan passport:client --personal`

*output*

```
Personal access client created successfully.
Client ID: 1
Client Secret: LbjQNxK5SQZ3pPrEBUwbkE8vaRkg8jh25Qh43HYy
```

---

You would need to use another middleware other then the default one because there is no user present when using this method

- Define client credentials alias middleware in kernel
- Add middleware to route
- Send request

#### Define client credentials middleware to the http kernel

Class `\App\Http\Kernel`:

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'client_credentials' => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials::class,
        //ommited
    ];
```

#### Define middleware on route

```php
Route::get('/test', 'ApiTestController@test')->middleware('client_credentials');
```

Class `\App\Http\Controllers\ApiTestController`:

```
public function test() {
        return response()->json(['data' => 'hey'] );
}
```

From `php artisan route:list`

```
GET|HEAD  | api/test | App\Http\Controllers\ApiTestController@test   | api,client_credentials  |
```

#### Send request

Following the specified request in the documentation on client-credentials-grant-tokens

I use Postman for simplicity, easily send test request with Postman (www.getpostman.com)

Set authorization to OAuth 2.0, image: [Postman authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHJou.png)

Set access token URL, client id, client secret and grant type to 'Client Credentials', image: [Postman OAuth Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6MN3.png)

Postman creates an token and appends it to URL or Header, in this case header

```
Accept:application/json
Authorization:Bearer eyJ0eXAiOi...KCjK0
```

Response:

```json
{
  "data": "hey"
}
```

Comment: OK, there is no way in Laravel Passport to "create an only client credentials client". But Am I Wrong for expecting it? Am I missing something around "machine-to-machine communication does not include any user interactions and does not impersonate any user and the access may not be restricted for a single user"?

Comment: The client authenticated though client credentials will act as an service account, no user impersonated and no user model involved. If you take an look at the create command in `\Laravel\Passport\ClientRepository::create`

Or `\Laravel\Passport\Console\ClientCommand::createPersonalClient`

The `user_id` will be left null and `$personalAccess` set to true

You cloud implement your own command with `ClientRepository` dependency injected in the handle method

Comment: and how to test it? I have problem testing client access token because Passport acting as helper need user object.

Comment: @rslhdyt, this is what I have done for testing:

* in `setUp`:
  * Create a client `assport::client()->fill([...])`
  * Make a request to `/oauth/token` and store access token in a property

* For every request you want to test, you'll need to a `Authorization` header containing: `Bearer {access_token}`

Answer (score 5):

These answers are a little old.

You can certainly add client credentials.

```
php artisan passport:client --client

protected $signature = 'passport:client
        {--personal : Create a personal access token client}
        {--password : Create a password grant client}
        {--client : Create a client credentials grant client}
        {--name= : The name of the client}
        {--provider= : The name of the user provider}
        {--redirect_uri= : The URI to redirect to after authorization }
        {--user_id= : The user ID the client should be assigned to }
        {--public : Create a public client (Auth code grant type only) }';
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It gave me a starting point to do my search to solve my specific problem.

Answer (score 4):

I was gonna comment but I don't have enough reputation yet =p

You could give the command a name parameter that won't require any user input. As far as how you would get that client secret over to your client without manual intervention is where the real wizardry would come in.

```
php artisan passport:client --personal --name={someName}
```

That command would still give you:

```
Personal access client created successfully.
Client ID: 1
Client Secret: LbjQNxK5SQZ3pPrEBUwbkE8vaRkg8jh25Qh43HYy
```

as expected.